# My Question Is About Implementing Login Page To SQL Server, Error In "Adapter.Fill(Table)"

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Sorry if i am posting this in the wrong section, i have no idea how any of this works and am a total noob to coding. I am however passionate and would like some help. I will respond quickly to any questions you guys may have so i can provide further information. Without further ado, here is my code. I will explain the issue below.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server = M's PC; Database = tyre_stocks_database_plain1.accdb; Integrated Security = true")

    Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Login_info where Username = @Username and Password = @Password", connection)

    command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text.ToString()
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text.ToString()


    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    adapter.Fill(table)

    If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username Or Password Is Invalid")

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")


    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

---

I am getting an error to do with "adapter.Fill(table)". The program states:

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'"

If it is still a bit unclear, i am trying to create a login page that "allows entry" to the user, provided they have the correct username and password that is stored in the database.

I have made sure that the connection to my Microsoft Access database is active by checking for the green plug sign next to the database name. If anyone could provide any information on how to help whatsoever i would be very grateful. Please bare in mind i am extremely new to coding and thus a total noob (as previously mentioned :P) i will respond promptly to any questions as to provide further information. Thank you fellow coders !

Comment: It seems that you are trying to connect to a non existent SQL server. However it looks like that you want to connect to an ms access db. If that's the case then [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2017) article may be helpful

Comment: You would have to use the OleDb library for an Access database.

Comment: As suggested, `SqlClient` is just for SQL Server and you need to use `OleDb` for Access.  If you want to connect to an ACCDB file then you need the ACE OLE DB provider installed.  If you have Office installed then you're good to go but just be aware that your users will need Office installed too or else you/they will have to install the Access Database Engine separately. You should visit [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) to learn how to write an appropriate connection string.

Comment: @Christos thank you! Since my database at the moment is very small with literally only 1 field for testing, do you recommend switching to MySQL for it to be an easier process ? Or is the difficulty the same? Thanks again!

Comment: @jmcilhinney i would like to apologise for my lack of knowledge in advance. I have the full office suite installed. What sort of changes should i make to my code so that it can be compatible with the Microsoft access database? Thanks for your response and thank you for any help/info you may provide!

Comment: Change your namespace import from `SqlClient` to `OleDb` and then use types from that namespace, e.g. `OleDbConnection` rather than `SqlConnection`. Follow the link I provided to learn how to write a connection string for Access.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @jmcilhinney, but the website is a little difficult to navigate as all the specialist terms there and names are new to me (like i said im a noob :( ) is it possible you could help put me in the right direction so i can see where to get this information from? thanks !

Comment: I'm not about providing people with code to copy and paste without any understanding. You've been told what the problem is and how to fix it.  If you don't understand the specifics then you need to do some research on the topic.  That's what noobs do: they learn things. All you need to do is change your ADO.NET provider, copy a connection string and change the path to the database. If you don't understand that then you should be doing reading on ADO.NET and with Access in particular.  There's loads of information around.

Comment: @jmcilhinney im not asking for the code brother... i am just asking you to refer to the correct section on the website... its okay though thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You didn't give the adapter the connection needed.

```
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command, connection)
```

Answer (score -1):

your code was missing Connection parameter. check line 15 where you need to supply the connection. Second thing is to check your connection string , it should have valid server and database names.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server = M's PC; Database = tyre_stocks_database_plain1.accdb; Integrated Security = true")

Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Login_info where Username = @Username and Password = @Password", connection)

command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text.ToString()
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text.ToString()

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command, connection)
Dim table As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(table)

If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Username Or Password Is Invalid")

Else

    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")


End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hey Pda Fox, thanks for your edit of the code, i have tried implementing this as you said:  Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command, connection)
        Dim table As New DataTable() however i get an error code that states overload resolution fails because no accessible "new" can be called within these arguments